# How batching works on sequential data?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have this sequential problem in `Tensorflow`, where I need to use `n` data as `input1` and `n+1` as `input2`.
This is my pseudo code:

```
for batch, data in enumerate(dataset):
   if batch == 0: 
      input1 = data  # take first row as input1 (n)
   else: 
      input2 = data # n+1
      train(input1, input2)
      input1 = input2 # input1 takes input2 value every steps since the next value depends on the last one
```

So `input1` takes `input2` previous value each iteration, since `n+1` depends on `n`.

But if I batch it, with that code, what I'll do is append first `batch_size` to `input1` and the next `batch_size` to `input2`, so that won't be sequential anymore. So my question comes out: is this type of sequential data available to batch? How?

PD: I create my dataset using:

```
def ds_creator(ds):
  return (ds
      .cache()
      .skip(5000)
      .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE))

dataset = ds_creator(dataset)
```

So batching my data isn't a problem since it can be solved by adding `.batch(batch_size)`

**edit: how my data looks like**
each input is a `Tensor` with `dtype=tf.string` and `shape=()`, for example:

```
tf.Tensor(b'Hello, I"m an user in StackOverflow', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of `n` and `n+1`?

Comment: @AloneTogether sure! i'm adding it now

Comment: Ok, so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @AloneTogether to be able to batch my data, but considering that `input1` and `input2` are consecutives

Comment: @AloneTogether parallelize my train so that it can be faster

Comment: if the result of 2 depends on the outcome of 1 then you can't really execute in parallel. However, you can still speed up the process by breaking them into multiple batches of says 1-10, 10-20, 20-30 etc and execute these batches in parallel. Obviously you going to ask how to get answer for 10 if the first batch is not finished. Maybe you did mutliple runs and you already know the answer for 10, 20, 30 :) - hopes this help.